# Pyspark - how to do case insensitive dataframe joins?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

Is there any nice looking code to perform case insensitive join in Pyspark?
Something like:

```py
df3 = df1.join(df2, 
               ["col1", "col2", "col3"],
               "left_outer",
               "case-insensitive")
```

Or what is your working solutions to this?

Answer (score 9):

It's not exactly elegant, but you could create new lower-case versions of those columns purely for joining.

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F
df1_l = df1 \
    .withColumn("col1_l", F.lower(df1.col1)) \
    .withColumn("col2_l", F.lower(df1.col2)) \
    .withColumn("col3_l"), F.lower(df1.col3)

df2_l = df2 \
    .withColumn("col1_l", F.lower(df2.col1)) \
    .withColumn("col2_l", F.lower(df2.col2)) \
    .withColumn("col3_l"), F.lower(df2.col3)

df3 = df1_l.join(df2_l, 
           ["col1_l", "col2_l", "col3_l"],
           "left_outer")
```

And you could also try doing this same transformation in a join predicate, e.g.:

```
df3 = df1.join(df2, 
           (F.lower(df1.col1) == F.lower(df2.col1))
            & (F.lower(df1.col2) == F.lower(df2.col2))
            & (F.lower(df1.col3) == F.lower(df2.col3))
           "left_outer")
```

Answer (score 4):

I believe the best way to achieve this is by transforming each of those `key`columns to **upper** or **lowercase** (maybe creating new columns or just applying that transformation over them), and then apply the join.

Answer (score 2):

I do this:
x = y.join(z, lower(y.userId) == lower(z.UserId))

Answer (score 0):

Well, as I understand there is no option than some pre-steps. I did it this way at the end:

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import udf
# udf ----------------------------
def upper(string):
    return string.upper()

upper = udf(upper)
# run ----------------------------
df1 =df1.select(df1.upper('col1'),df1.upper('col2'),df1.upper('col3'))
df2 =df2.select(df2.upper('col1'),df2.upper('col2'),df2.upper('col3'))
# join ---------------------------
df3 = df1.join(df2,["col1", "col2", "col3"])
```

Comment: to not waste resources and get a lower performance you should rely on internal spark functions if exist. UDFs should only be used if needed. See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51607061/how-to-compare-strings-without-case-sensitive-in-spark-rdd