# How to Compare Strings without case sensitive in Spark RDD?

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

I have following Dataset

```
drug_name,num_prescriber,total_cost
AMBIEN,2,300
BENZTROPINE MESYLATE,1,1500
CHLORPROMAZINE,2,3000
```

Wanted to find out number of A's and B's from above DataSet along with the header. I am using the following code to find out num of A's and number of B's.

```
from pyspark import SparkContext
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession

logFile = 'Sample.txt'
spark = SparkSession.builder.appName('GD App').getOrCreate()
logData = spark.read.text(logFile).cache()

numAs = logData.filter(logData.value.contains('a')).count()
numBs = logData.filter(logData.value.contains('b')).count()
print('{0} {1}'.format(numAs,numBs))
```

It returned the output as `1 1`. I wanted to compare without the case sensitivity. I have tried the following, but it is returning the error as `'Column' object is not callable`

```
numAs = logData.filter((logData.value).tolower().contains('a')).count()
numBs = logData.filter((logData.value).tolower().contains('b')).count()
```

Please help me out.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To convert to lower case, you should use the `lower()` function (see [here](http://spark.apache.org/docs/2.1.0/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.functions.lower)) from `pyspark.sql.functions`.So you could try:

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

logData = spark.createDataFrame(
    [
     (0,'aB'),
     (1,'AaA'),
     (2,'bA'),
     (3,'bB')
    ],
    ('id', "value")
)
numAs = logData.filter(F.lower((logData.value)).contains('a')).count()
```

---

You mention 'I am using the following code to find out num of A's and number of B's.' Note that if you want to count the actual occurrences of a character instead of  the amount of rows that contain the character, you could do something like:

```
def count_char_in_col(col: str, char: str):
    return F.length(F.regexp_replace(F.lower(F.col(col)), "[^" + char + "]", ""))

logData.select(count_char_in_col('value','a')).groupBy().sum().collect()[0][0]
```

which in the above example will return `5`.

Hope this helps!